# Android Studio - How to get time from my timer

Tags: android, android-studio

I have a timer and want to record the time when paused.

This is my timer:

```
 private Runnable updateTimerMethod = new Runnable() {

    public void run() {

        timeInMillies = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - startTime;
        finalTime = timeSwap + timeInMillies;

        SetReturnTime(finalTime);


        int seconds = (int) (finalTime / 1000);
        int minutes = seconds / 60;
        seconds = seconds % 60;
        int milliseconds = (int) (finalTime % 1000);
        textTimer.setText("" + minutes + ":"
                + String.format("%02d", seconds) + ":"
                + String.format("%03d", milliseconds));
        myHandler.postDelayed(this, 0);
//txt.setText("oxy="+oxy);


    }

};

int sss=0;

public void SetReturnTime(long t){

   sss  = (int) (t/1000);

}

public long ReturnTime(){
    return sss;
}
```

These are the start/pause buttons:

```
    startButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnStart);
    startButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            startTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
            myHandler.postDelayed(updateTimerMethod, 0);
            startcount_now = true;

        }
    });

    pauseButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnPause);
    pauseButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            timeSwap += timeInMillies;
            myHandler.removeCallbacks(updateTimerMethod);


        }
    });
```

Class that will use the time:

```
Button btnCalSpeed;
private EditText distance;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_speed_input);

    distance = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtDistance);


    btnCalSpeed = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCalSpeed);
    btnCalSpeed.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {

            String distanceToString = distance.getText().toString();
            int IntDistance = new Integer(distanceToString).intValue();
            //int timeTraveled = (int) (finalTime / 1000);

            double Avgspeed = IntDistance/2;

                    Toast toast = new Toast(getApplicationContext());
            toast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP| Gravity.LEFT, 0, 0);
            toast.makeText(SpeedInput.this,"Speed = "+ ReturnTime(), toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    });

}




@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_speed_input, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Yet, somehow when I display `sss`, the value is 0. Is there any way to solve this? I want to store the final time (in milliseconds), and change it to seconds, when the "pause" button is clicked.

Comment: Where is your code do you actually display sss?

Comment: yep, i use a new class which extends to the class that contains a timer. And the call the returntime() method.

Comment: I suggest you add some log statements to figure out why sss never gets updated from 0

Comment: i am new to android, can you tell how can i do that?

Comment: `Log.d("message", "print me");` then you need to figure out where and how to read the logcat in Android Studio

Comment: in my situation, i show put this statement to where?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

/* Method One:Your Current Class from where you want to send to your target class */

```
Intent i=new Intent(ActivityA.this,ActivityB.class);
i.putExtra("sss",""+sss);
startActivity(i);
```

/* Your Target Class in onCreate method*/

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String sss = intent.getStringExtra("sss");
Log.e("ValueOfsss",""+sss);
```

/* Method 2: on your target Class(ActivityB) simply do here SourceClassName is ActivityA */

```
Log.e("ValueOfsss",""+ActivityA.sss);
```

Comment: in Method 2, what is the format of the YourSourceActivityNAme

Comment: in method one context is your sourceClassName means if you are sending the data from ActivityA to ActivityB then ActivityA is your sourceClassName and ActivityB is your targetClassName.

Answer (score 0):

/* Try this,I am not sure */

```
    public static int sss=0;  
    private Runnable updateTimerMethod = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {

        timeInMillies = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - startTime;
        finalTime = timeSwap + timeInMillies;
        sss=SetReturnTime(finalTime);
        int seconds = (int) (finalTime / 1000);
        int minutes = seconds / 60;
        seconds = seconds % 60;
        int milliseconds = (int) (finalTime % 1000);
        textTimer.setText("" + minutes + ":"
                + String.format("%02d", seconds) + ":"
                + String.format("%03d", milliseconds));
        myHandler.postDelayed(this, 0);
//txt.setText("oxy="+oxy);
    }
};

public int SetReturnTime(long t){

   sss  = (int) (t/1000);
   return sss;

}

public long ReturnTime(){
    return sss;
}

pauseButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnPause);
    pauseButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            timeSwap += timeInMillies;
            myHandler.removeCallbacks(updateTimerMethod);
       Log.e("getPausedTime",""+sss);

       }
    });
```

Comment: use the above code ,i edited it , see you are getting the value in pause button ?

Comment: i think you will get the value of sss while pressing pauseButton,check your logcat.

Comment: if you getting the right answer then try to upvote the code, so that next person not have to think to much. :)

Comment: but i still can't get this in the next class

Comment: You want value of sss in next class?